# SSH or telnet as an unpriviledged user leads to 'socket: Permission denied' error

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, socket, telnet

I'm running a strange 3.0.35 heavily patched kernel on an embedded device (Kobo eReader). Maybe it partly explains this issue.
Basically:

```
kobo:/$ ssh root@127.0.0.1
socket: Permission denied
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: failure
kobo:/$ telnet 127.0.0.1
telnet: socket: Permission denied
kobo:/$
```

Then I can do this without any problem:

```
kobo:/$ su root
Password:
kobo:/# ssh root@127.0.0.1
root@127.0.0.1's password: 
Welcome to InkBox OS!
* Warning *
Root filesystem is mounted read-only.
Invoke `ifsctl mnt rootfs rw' to make it read-write.
kobo:~#
```

It seems, according to the stack trace, that `AF_INET` socket creation as an unpriviledged user is the main hurdle:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Is there anything I can do to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: there is an Android patch restricting socket use. Up to you to know if this patch landed on your Kobo (is that its normal kernel anyway?). Name of the option: CONFIG_ANDROID_PARANOID_NETWORK   https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/2038692b9acf7ae3054a35e879039ff062316bf0%5E!/ . See also on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451444/what-can-cause-a-socket-permission-denied-error

Comment: Thanks, it's really strange, how could that be enabled on some random device that by default only uses root and is not paranoid about any security at all. But it was...